# DeepExplainer applied - Ressource Exhausted Error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, shap

I'm trying to make my deep neural network explainable, however, I keep on getting an error that the resources are exhausted. I assume it's behause of the `flatten()` applied to `x_train_1` and `x_train_2`, however, I do not another way to approach this since feeding in a tensor is not supported. Here is a reproducable example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import get_session
import numpy as np
import shap 

inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(62490), name="left_inp")
inp2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(62490), name="other_inp")
main_inp = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([inp, inp2])
intermediate_outp = tf.keras.layers.Dense(624900)(main_inp)
outp = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(intermediate_outp) for _ in range(2)] # to simulate multiple outputs
simple_model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=[inp, inp2],
    outputs=outp,
)
simple_model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
simple_model.summary()


x_train_1 = np.random.randint(0, 62490, size=(10, 6249,1))
x_train_2 = np.random.randint(0, 62490, size=(10, 6249,1))
x_test_1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10,1))
x_test_2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10,1))

#X_test_flatten1 = X_train[np.random.choice(X_train.shape[0], 10, replace=False)].flatten()
#X_test_flatten2 = X_train_phase[np.random.choice(X_train_phase.shape[0], 10, replace=False)].flatten()
# Skipping the simple_model.fit(...) for now
X_test_flatten1 = x_train_1#.flatten()
X_test_flatten2 = x_train_2#.flatten()

explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(simple_model, [X_test_flatten1, X_test_flatten2])
shap_values = explainer.shap_values([x_test_1, x_test_2])

shap.initjs()

i = 5
test_inp = [x_test_1[i].reshape(1,-1), x_test_2[i].reshape(1,-1)]
pred = simple_model.predict(test_inp)
print("model outputs: {}".format(pred))
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[0], np.concatenate([shap_values[0][0], shap_values[0][1]], axis=1)[i])
```

Comment: [ResourceExhaustedError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/errors/ResourceExhaustedError) is about running out of gpu ram, cpu, ram. You should provide us your hardware information too.

Comment: When executing the code do you get the same error?

Comment: I'm using an Intel Core-i7 CPU @ 2.80 GHz with HD Graphics 630 GPU.

Comment: How much space does your ram have?

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code on Google Colab with GPU Tesla T4 and 12 gb of ram,

`!nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.39       Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   63C    P0    30W /  70W |   1072MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

with tensorflow 1 `%tensorflow_version 1.x`

Your model have about 78 billion parameters which consumed about 1 gb of ram and 1 gb of gpu.

[image]

That's why when run on your computer, it got exhausted.

[Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12HJQi1LaSUqE6_OPDhQEuNiAlZa4IaRx?usp=sharing)